# JTable showing previous data on hovering/clicking/scrolling over new data

Tags: java, swing

So I have two methods **method_1** and **method_2**. Both these methods are identical, just a minor change in **for loop**. On the event of a button being clicked,**method_1** gets executed and I get the data as intended in the JTable, similarly when clicking on the 2nd button, **method_2** gets executed and i get the results, however when I hover over the table header, the previous column names shows and on clicking the rows or scrolling , previous data are overwritten.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane_2;
DefaultTableModel model;
JTable table;

public void method_1(){
    String[][] data = new String[10][4];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            data[i][j] = "one";

    String[] column = { "Column_1", "Column_2", "Column_3", "Column_4"};
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, column);
    table = new JTable(model);
    scrollPane_2 = new JScrollPane(table);
    panel_6.add(scrollPane_2);
    panel_6.revalidate();
}

public void method_2(){
    String[][] data = new String[8][2];
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
            data[i][j] = "Row_"+i;

    String[] column = { "Column_1", "Column_2"};
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, column);
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    table = new JTable(model);
    scrollPane_2 = new JScrollPane(table);
    panel_6.add(scrollPane_2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel_6.revalidate();
}
```

Tried revalidate() and repaint() on scollPane and the panel, also fireTableDataChanged() on the DefaultTableModel without any success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
panel_6.add(scrollPane_2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Adding another component to the CENTER does NOT remove the previous component that was added to the CENTER. Swing default painting will paint components in the reverse order they were added to the container. So effectively both components get painted but you see the last one painted. However this can cause problems with events being dispatched to different components causing painting problems.

Don't keep creating new JTable and JScrollPane components.

Instead, when you want to change the data in the table all you need to do is change the model of the existing JTable. So all you need is:

```
table.setModel( theNewModel );
```

No need to fire events or revalidate() or anything.

Comment: that did the trick...creating new JTable and JScrollPane was giving the problem.